# Error object changes into xdebug_message when viewed in Sentry

Tags: php, xdebug, sentry, monolog

I currently have 2 Monolog Handlers set up.
One redirects errors/exceptions to `stderr` and one sends them to Sentry.

```php
$pimple[Logger::class] =  function (ContainerInterface $container): Logger {
    $monologLogger = new Logger('logger');

    #Stream Logs to stderr
    $streamHandler = new StreamHandler('php://stderr');

    #Send Logs to Sentry
    \Sentry\init(
        [
            'dsn' => 'http://key@url/project_id',
            'default_integrations' => false
        ]);

    $sentryHandler = new Handler(SentrySdk::getCurrentHub(), Logger::NOTICE);

    $jsonFormatter = new JsonFormatter();

    $streamHandler->setFormatter($jsonFormatter);
    $sentryHandler->setFormatter($jsonFormatter);

    $monologLogger->pushProcessor(function ($record) {
        if (isset($record['context']['error']) && is_array($record['context'])) {
            foreach ($record['context'] as $key => $value) {
                if ($key === 'tags') {
                    //Handled natively by Sentry monolog handler
                    continue;
                }
                $record['context']['extra'][$key] = is_string($value) && json_decode($value) !== null ? json_decode($value) : $value;
            }
        }
        return $record;
    });

    $monologLogger->pushHandler($streamHandler);
    $monologLogger->pushHandler($sentryHandler);

    return $monologLogger;
};
```

My problem is that when looking at stderr, the error context looks like this, which is exactly what I want it to look like, because it tells me exactly what I need to know to identify the error.

```json
"error":{"class":"Error","message":"Call to undefined function Presentation\\Web\\Action\\Nodes\\div()","code":0,"file":"/Presentation/Web/Action/Nodes/GetNodesAction.php:19"}
```

But this is how they appear in Sentry, which make it very difficult to properly read it.

```json
"error":{ xdebug_message: 
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Error: Call to undefined function Presentation\Web\Action\Nodes\div() in /Presentation/Web/Action/Nodes/GetNodesAction.php on line <i>19</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0009</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>471848</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='/app/test/web/index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0060</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>472120</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>require( <font color='#00bb00'>'/app/web/index.php'</font> )</td><td title='/app/test/web/index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../index.php<b>:</b>14</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.6470</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1460136</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Slim\App->run(  )</td><td title='/app/web/index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../index.php<b>:</b>9</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.7036</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1609552</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Slim\App->process(  )</td><td title='/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../App.php<b>:</b>297</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>5</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.7511</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1740704</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack(  )</td><td title='/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../App.php<b>:</b>392</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>6</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.7511</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1740704</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Slim\App->Slim\{closure:/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php:63-78}(  )</td><td title='/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../MiddlewareAwareTrait.php<b>:</b>117</td></tr>
... rest of the output omitted ...
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can make sure the object doesn't change?